# i have a one table and that contains images with multiple categoryis

Tags: php, mysql

here my problem is   i want to diplay images on my page but it shows all images 
so i want display one images with same category

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT5UT.png)

here is my database 
also 
i try this query$sql=$db->query('SELECT tbl_gallery.*,

tbl_gallery_category.*
from tbl_gallery   LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_gallery_category on tbl_gallery.name = tbl_gallery_category.`gallery-cat-id`' UNION  SELECT tbl_gallery.*,
tbl_gallery_category.*from tbl_gallery    RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_gallery_category on tbl_gallery.name = tbl_gallery_category.`gallery-cat-id`' );

Comment: Lose the single quotes around the column name, i.e. use this: `WHERE gallery-cat-id = 5` (or possibly `WHERE gallery-cat-id = '5'`).

Comment: make query like this  SELECT category_name FROM tbl_gallery_category WHERE 'gallery-cat-id'=5

Comment: For start put one space between table and where clause: `SELECT category_name FROM tbl_gallery_category WHERE 'gallery-cat-id'=5`

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this :

```
"SELECT category_name FROM '".TABLE."' WHERE gallery-cat-id = '".$cid."' "
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query to get your results

```
SELECT `category_name` FROM ".TABLE." WHERE `gallery-cat-id`= '".$cid."'
```